# SQL join columns from 2 tables into 1 new table, no duplicates?

Tags: sql, join, unique, distinct, union

I'm trying to get a single column from 2 tables that have nothing to do with each other. I want a single table with a column of links to my favorites, and a column of DISTINCT links to my recent history (instead of having 2 separate tables with one column each). I've tried lots of nested queries, unions, joins, etc but I still have duplicates. I want ALL of my favorites, but not ALL of my history (there's thousands of records). So if I use top 10 to filter down history, I might be cutting favorites short as I could have 15.

If I have 15 favorites I want all of those, and if 15 is the number then show top 15 recent with no repeats. Is this ever remotely possible?

```
select distinct t1.id, ('<a href='+rtrim(t1.pagename)+'.htm>'+rtrim(t1.favname)+'</a>') as favorite, ('<a href='+rtrim(t2.screen)+'_S.htm>'+rtrim(t2.screen)+'</a>') as recent 
from (select web2favname.pagename, web2favname.favname, row_number() over (partition by null order by (select NULL)) as id
      from web2favname
     ) t1 join
     (select distinct top 20 screen, row_number() over (partition by null order by (select NULL)) as id
      from usertrace
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
```

I'm just guessing the top number, but it still shows repeats of the favorites. :/[image]

Comment: what do you exactly mean by duplicates?the result set you are retrieving can't be thought of as a table.

Comment: I am making a Datatable of links with the data. There are duplicates in the left column of favorites, and duplicates in the right column of recent.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly if the number of favorites is n you want to show n favorites and n history records?  If so then why not just do this with 3 separate queries? First to get the count, then select all favorites, then select top n from history?   You can do that either in code or in a stored procedure.

Comment: Okay, how could I do that?